# Pandas - Summarize values between two rows between two values

Tags: python, pandas

I have been thinking in a more efficient way to summarize values in a dataframe between two values.

So, I have this dataframe:

```
   Event   Value
   ==============
   Start   -
   Action  11
   Action  6
   Action  3
   End     -
   Start   -
   Action  8
   Action  6
   End     -
```

So what I want to do is sum all the values between **Start** and **End** and store the value in the initial **Start**

```
   Event    Value
   ==============
   Start   20
   Action  11
   Action  6
   Action  3
   End     -
   Start   14
   Action  8
   Action  6
   End     -
```

Is there a way to do this without using loops?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: initial Start as in the very start or the First Start you encounter from the End? In your case, are you talking about first start or second?

Comment: The idea is between a Start and End Event summarize all the actions. I am checking now the answer of @scott-boston, and will tell how it goes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace('-', np.nan).astype(float)

df['Value'] = (df.groupby(df['Event'].eq('Start').cumsum())['Value']
                 .transform('sum')
                 .mask(df['Event'] != 'Start', df['Value'])
                 .fillna('-'))
```

Output:

```
    Event Value
1   Start    20
2  Action    11
3  Action     6
4  Action     3
5     End     -
6   Start    14
7  Action     8
8  Action     6
9     End     -
```

Details:

- Use `groupby` on a `cumsum` of events where event equals 'Start', to
  create groups
- Then use `transfrom` to calculate sum and `mask` events not equal to
  start with the original 'Value'
- And then use `fillna` to get '-' character back

Comment: I am checking it now, will tell you soon how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome this is working already, now I just notice that I need to add one more condition, having another column with an id, and only if they have the same id I need to sum them, otherwise ignore, but I am trying to solve it. Thanks for your help!!